# ec2 LAMP REDhat distro change mysql password error

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

i am on ec2 plain linux and wish to change my mySQL password 
ive tried:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root -p '***old***' password '***new****'
```

then it prompts me to enter password
then i enter `***old***`

but i keep getting an error message

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

question: how do i change my current password?

edit:
when i put this in, no space in between -p and the old password i get a list of definition

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root -p'***old***'
```

when i put this in

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root -p password '***new***'
```

i get the same error message as above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you use the short option form (`-p`), you cannot have a space between the option and the password. Additionally, If you specify the password as part of the command, you should not be prompted for it (however, because of the space, your password is actually recognized as a separate command). [(1)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqladmin.html#option_mysqladmin_password)

   - It would be better to let the system prompt you for your password - this avoids confusion with spaces, quoting, and special characters, and the password doesn't show up in your history. (Note that the old password is omitted):

     ```
     sudo mysqladmin -u root -p password 'NEW_PASSWORD'
     ```
2. Passwords containing special characters must be enclosed in single quotes (which you have already done). [(2)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqladmin.html#command_mysqladmin_password)
3. Alternatively, you can perform the entire task using the mysql client and queries [(3)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/set-password.html):

   ```
   mysql -u root -p
   Enter password:
   mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('NEW_PASSWORD') WHERE User='root';
   mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```

   (Note the above will change the password for all 'Hosts'. You can add `AND Host='localhost'` to restrict it to just localhost.)

   - Alternatively, at the mysql prompt, you can use:

     ```
     mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('NEW_PASSWORD');
     ```

If you can't login to mysql directly (`mysql -u root -p`), then you have a different problem - possibly relating to special characters in your password (I find this is true when entering a password with special characters in `mysql_secure_installation`). The MySQL manual describes how to reset a root password, if needed, [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix).

Comment: dont have any special characters, tried running sql queries in mysql workbench but got errors

Comment: a) Can you login to the mysql client (`mysql -u root -p`) or do you get 'Access Denied'? b) What were the errors? c) Also are you specifically running RedHat (you use it in your title, but wrote 'ec2 plain linux' in your question). d) Just to confirm, your MySQL server is running on the same EC2 instance that you are running the commands from, right?

Comment: it is a redhat distro, linux on ec2. question a. i am getting the same error as above. question d. yes.  note: i am not logged in as root, i have been using sudo

Comment: The error given almost always means that you have the wrong password. You could try `mysql --no-defaults -u root -p` to ensure that no option files are overriding your password, but otherwise (and especially since you are trying to change your password anyway) I may suggest simply resetting your mysql root password and proceeding from there.

Comment: logged in mysql -u myuser -p, i the username for mysql was different. THANK YOU!!!!